# How to set system property using gradle?

Tags: gradle

I was wondering if it's possible to set a system property, for a Java application, using Gradle?

I tried using gradle.properties file and defining a property as

```
systemProp.name = my name
```

but then when I try to get that property from a Java application using

```
System.getProperty("name")
```

that property is not found.

build.gradle and gradle.properties are in root folder of the project.

This is what my build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.8.6'
    }
}

appengine {
    httpPort = 8081
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject.extensions', name: 'guice-servlet', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.2.0.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.27'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.8.6'
    compile 'com.google.template:soy:2012-12-21'
    compile 'org.json:json:20090211'
}
```

And this is what my build.properties look like:

```
systemProp.firstName=Marko
systemProp.lastName=Vuksanovic
```

This is part of an AppEngine application and I run it using the following command:

```
gradle appengineRun
```

Comment: How does your build code look like that runs the Java app? Please post your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system property set in `gradle.properties` will be available only in JVM where Gradle is running.

From [gradle-appengine-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) documentation:

> appengineRun: Starts a local development server running your project
>   code.
>
> jvmFlags: The JVM flags to pass on to the local development server.

If you need your system properties to be available in app engine, which is separate JVM, you should use `jvmFlags` property.

Explicitly:

```
appengine {
    jvmFlags = ['-DfirstName=Marko', '-DlastName=Vuksanovic']
}
```

With gradle.properties:

```
appengine {
    jvmFlags = ['-DfirstName=$firstName', '-DlastName=$lastName']
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I just stumbled on this for use with the gradle application plugin. Add to the run task. Works great:

```
run {   
    systemProperties['MYPROP'] = '/my/prop/value'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, getting `> Could not find method run() for arguments [build_3q2qbgis9k2n97muogsnwks4i$_run_closure5@3172da27]`

Comment: @birgersp The answer mentions `gradle application plugin`. Just add this plugin to your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 15):

This is how I do it, setting props for [Selenide](http://selenide.org/) test framework:

```
test {
    systemProperty "browser", "chrome"
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", "$projectDir/drivers/chromedriver"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me (using Kotlin DSL):

```
tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
        systemProperty("key", "value")
}
```